# To be backwards compatible, are you supposed to use ARB extensions instead of core calls?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

For example, I quote the wiki:

> Note that glDrawTransformFeedback​ is perfectly capable of rendering from a transform feedback object without having to query the number of vertices. Though this is only core in GL 4.0, it is widely available on 3.x-class hardware

I assume this means there is an extension for it. When using an openGL library, would I want to do the normal core 4.0 call, or would I want to do an ARB extension call?

I would assume that the extension could target older hardware + newer hardware, and the 4.0 call would only target the newer hardware. Or am I safe to use 4.0 calls and then somehow the older hardware is forward compatible enough to simulate that call using the extension or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extensions that are ***promoted to core*** share, among other things, the same enumerants as their equivalent *core* functionality.

If, for example, you look at the constants that [`GL_EXT_transform_feedback`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/transform_feedback.txt) introduced, they are the very same as the constants without the `_EXT` suffix in *OpenGL 3.0* (this extension was promoted to core in 3.0).

```
GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD_EXT       = 0x8C89  (GL_EXT_transform_feedback)
GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD           = 0x8C89  (Core OpenGL 3.0)
```

ARB extensions are *not* the only source of extensions that are promoted into core. There are EXT, NV, APPLE, ATI (AMD) and SGI extensions that are also now a part of the core OpenGL API.

---

Basically, if you have a version where an extension has been promoted to core, you should ask the driver for the proc. address of the function by its ***core*** name and not the extension it originated in.

#### The reason is pretty easy to demonstrate:

I have an *OpenGL 4.4* implementation from NV that ***does not*** implement [`GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/APPLE/vertex_array_object.txt) even though that extension was promoted to core in *OpenGL 3.0*. Instead, this NV driver implements the derivative [`GL_ARB_vertex_array_object`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_array_object.txt) extension.

If your software was written to expect `GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object` because that is an extension that was officially promoted to core, you might get the completely wrong idea about my GPU/driver.

However, if you took a look at the context version and saw **4.4**, you would know that `glGenVertexArrays (...)` is guaranteed to be available and you do not have to load the APPLE function that this driver knows nothing about: `glGenVertexArraysAPPLE (...)`.

---

#### Last, regarding the statement you quoted:

> Note that glDrawTransformFeedback​ is perfectly capable of rendering from a transform feedback object without having to query the number of vertices. Though this is only core in GL 4.0, it is widely available on 3.x-class hardware.

That pertains to [GL_ARB_transform_feedback2](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/transform_feedback2.txt). That extension does not require GL4 class hardware, but was not included as core in 3.3 when the ARB did the whole 3.3/4.0 split. If you have core *OpenGL 4.0*, or your driver lists this extension (*as 3.3 implementations may, but are **not required** to*), then that behavior is guaranteed to apply.

> #### [OpenGL 4.0 Core Profile Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec40.core.20100311.pdf)  -  J.1 New Features  -  pp. 424
>
> > #### Additional transform feedback functionality including:
> >
> > > - transform feedback objects which encapsulate transform feedback-related state;
> > > - the ability to pause and resume transform feedback operations; and
> > > - ***the ability to draw primitives captured in transform feedback mode without querying captured primitive count***
> > >         (GL_ARB_transform_feedback2).

Comment: so in this case, would I use the GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 or would ask for the proc. address... what's the proc address and how do i ask the driver for it?

Comment: @BlazArt: "The proc. address" refers to the mechanism you use to load an extension from a driver at run-time. Since you are unfamiliar with the term, I think you are probably using something like GLEW or another language that does this for you. Some extensions, before being promoted to core, will have an extra suffix at the end of their function names (e.g. `glGenBuffersARB` for `GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object`, became `glGenBuffers` when promoted to core). `GL_ARB_transform_feedback2` has no extra suffix, so the core function has the same name as the extension function: `glBindTransformFeedback`